# JavaScript Promise.all code does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, promise

I have the following code fetching information from a mySQL DB.
The DB includes several tables, among them an `Activity` table, having a channelId field, a `Channel` table having a userId field, and a `User` table having a userName field.
The function `getAllProjectACtivities(user,project)` returns a promise of an array of `Activity` objects, each including all `Activity` table fields.
The function `findChannel(channelId)` returns a promise of a single `Channel` object, including all `Channel` table fields.
The function `findUser(userId)` returns a promise of a single `User` object, including all `User` table fields.
All 3 functions hide a JSON Ajax request to the DB, and have been tested to work properly standalone.

What I'm trying to do here is get a list of activities, for each of them get the channel, for each of the channels get the user.
Then I build a table of activites comprising of 2 activity fields and one user field.

For this I need a 3 phase DB access yielding arrays of objects. Below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var projNum=1;
    var userNum=1;
    var globalActivityList; //this global array will store data from the beginning of the promise chain to be used at the end of the chain
    $('#tableContainer').append('<table border="0" style="background-color: lightblue;"></table>');
    var table = $('#tableContainer').children();
//here goes:
    getUserProjectActivities(userNum,projNum)
        .then(function (activityList){
            table.append("<tr><th>Number</th><th>Description</th><th>Employee</th></tr>");
            globalActivityList=activityList;
            return Promise.all(activityList.map(function(activity){
                //alert(activity.activityChannelId);//******** shows the right stuff
                findChannel(activity.activityChannelId);
            }));
        })
        .then(function (channelList){
            alert (channelList.length);//******* gives the right size
            alert (channelList);//******** u-oh, this shows ,,,,,,,,,,,, - the array is empty.<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Problem
            return Promise.all(channelList.map(function(channel){
                findUser(channel.channelEmployeeId);
            }));
        })
        .then(function(userList){
            for (var i=0; i<userList.length; i++){
                var tableString="<tr>";
                tableString+="<td>"+globalActivityList[i].activitityId+"</td>";
                tableString+="<td>"+globalActivityList[i].activitityDescription+"</td>";
                tableString+="<td>"+userList[i].userName+"</td>";
                tableString+="</tr>";
                table.append(tableString);
            }
        })
});
```

What happens is the second .then gets an array without information, and ofcourse all subsequent code fails.
Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate of [Promise.all is returning an array of undefined and resolves before being done](/q/34813147/4642212). Your question is older, but the other question has accumulated a lot more traction and presents the problem and solution more cleanly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those callbacks need to `return` a promise, as they are asynchronous. Your `map` invocations currently produce an array of `undefined`s that are fed into `Promise.all`. It needs to be

```
return Promise.all(activityList.map(function(activity){
    return findChannel(activity.activityChannelId);
//  ^^^^^^
}));
```

and

```
return Promise.all(channelList.map(function(channel){
    return findUser(channel.channelEmployeeId);
//  ^^^^^^
}));
```

---

Notice that your `globalActivityList` is rather an antipattern. It would be better if for each activitiy you would create one object that includes channel and user, so that the list of all these objects becomes result of a single promise - no need to leave the chain:

```
getUserProjectActivities(userNum, projNum)
  .then(function(activityList) {
      table.append("<tr><th>Number</th><th>Description</th><th>Employee</th></tr>");
      return Promise.all(activityList.map(function(activity) 
          return findChannel(activity.activityChannelId);
            .then(function(channel) {
                return findUser(channel.channelEmployeeId);
            })
            .then(function(user) {
                // maybe unnecessary intermediate object
                return {activity:activity.activityID, description:activity.activityDescription, user:user.userName};
            })
            .then(function(item) {
                var tableString="<tr>";
                tableString+="<td>"+item.activitity+"</td>";
                tableString+="<td>"+item.description+"</td>";
                tableString+="<td>"+item.user+"</td>";
                tableString+="</tr>";
                return tableString;
            });
      }));
  })
  .then(function (list) {
      for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
          table.append(list[i]);
      }
  });
```

Comment: Enjoy your silver badge :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Oh, thanks - I'm a bit late to [the party](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4124/promise) :-)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I'll do my best!

Comment: @Bergi +1 for a quick fix, +2 for the second implementation. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with how you use `.map`. The callback in `.map` should return something.

`.all` expects an array of promises, and that's not what you're giving it, because you're not using `.map` correctly.

The pattern of using `Promise.all(arr.map(...))` is meant to map the array into an array of promises. Since you're not returning anything from the callback in `.map`, you're not giving `.all` what it expects.

I believe you meant `return findUser(...);` and `return findChannel(...);` (assuming they return promises).

Comment: you're right. I guess learning promises and array.map the same day was a bit too much... ;)